# setPageLoad() not working in Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I need to set the page size of my SQLite database. By default, it is set to 4096. But for my requirement, I need it to be 1024.

I have used the following, but they are not working:

```
db.rawQuery("PRAGMA page_size=1024",null);
setPageLoad();
```

I understand that this needs to be done before adding any data in the database.

I have also tried adding these lines to `onConfigure(), onCreate(), onOpen()` methods, and also after getting a database object from `dbhelper.getReadableDatabase(); dbhelper.getWritableDatabase()` methods.

Comment: Try running `VACUUM` after setting the page size; this will change the page size even if you've already created tables.

Comment: @Colonel its working with VACUUM command. Thanks you.. Can you post this as answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more of a workaround than an actual solution, but if you run `VACUUM` after setting the page size, it will rebuild the database (keeping the data) with the new page size (unless the database is in WAL mode).

Note that `VACUUM` is pretty expensive, so don't run it if you don't need to.